# Is it possible to skip releases during an upgrade?

Tags: installation, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade straight from a very old release to the latest one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/how-do-i-upgrade-straight-from-a-very-old-release-to-the-latest-one)

Is it possible to upgrade a 10.04 lucid installation to 11.04 Natty, without upgrading to 10.10 first? What about other versions?