# Can I upgrade from 10.04 to 11.04 using iso image 

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to skip releases during an upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45666/is-it-possible-to-skip-releases-during-an-upgrade)

I'm using 10.04 as only OS on my 32-Bit PC (Not dual boot). Can I upgrade to 11.04 using ***ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso*** file without burning on CD  or installing on USB drives. I don't have internet connection, so I cannot download alternate version too. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it your 10.04 Os 32bit?

Comment: Yes dude. Edited in the post too. Thnx.

Comment: Do have installed `gisomount` or `gmountiso`?

Comment: @ Achu No dude. If it is a small app then I can install with my very slow internet connection. Is it?

Answer (score 2):

**UNDER NO CIRCUMSTANCES SHOULD YOU UPGRADE DIRECT TO 11.04 FROM 10.04**

Despite the appearances, you should never upgrade to 11.04 without missing out 10.10, even with the desktop or alternate CDs.

See this [AU answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20667/upgrade-ubuntu-10-04-to-11-04) for more details -

In summary, it is not supported, you will likely cause major issues with your install, or even break it so that it will not boot.

If you want to use the desktop CD, backup your non-hidden /home folder files and do a fresh install.  After that, copy back your /home folder files.

Answer (score 0):

I should point out now that I have no experience with upgrading in this manner, and that the following is what I would do if I were going to do it myself for the first time.

You can do this by adding the ISO to APT's list of repositories, documentation for which can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptCdrom).

First you need to mount the ISO so APT can find it. Open a terminal and move into the directory in which the ISO is currently sitting. Let's say it's currently in your Downloads folder, you would type

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Once you're there, you need to create a directory into which to mount it. Type

```
mkdir upgrade
```

to create a directory called 'upgrade' in the current directory. Now you can mount the ISO into your upgrade directory by typing

```
mount -o loop -t iso9660 ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso ~/Downloads/upgrade
```

You may need to precede the above command with `sudo` - I'm not sure how permissions will work if you try mounting it in a user-owned directory. Now you just need to add this upgrade directory, and with it your upgrade ISO, to APT's sources list.

```
sudo apt-cdrom add 
sudo apt-cdrom ident 
sudo apt-cdrom -d "upgrade" -r
```

From here, it's just a simple case of running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and APT will pull the new packages out of the mounted ISO. Once the upgrade is complete, you can delete the `upgrade` directory as it is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 'mkdir upgrade' path?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Will this upgrade be destructive in any manner ? Last time I tried to upgrade, it deleted almost all of my /var/ directory

Comment: The upgrade process will be the same regardless of the particular path chosen. At the end of the day, once the installer gets going, it's still the same process. I'm not sure exactly what directories are affected during the upgrade process, and to what degree. If you're having an issue with directories being deleted, then you should probably pose it as a new question.

Comment: @ Chris You mentioned, 'mkdir upgrade', what is the path of upgrade folder?

Comment: I'd spotted a mistake with regard to the `upgrade` directory and I've updated the answer with the correction. The `upgrade` directory is now located in your Downloads folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Mount the iso file**

**Note**: You cannot skip versions when upgrading [AU-answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20667/upgrade-ubuntu-10-04-to-11-04)

But to install ubuntu from ISO file follow this:

Creat a mount directory called `cd-image` on your home directory.

Then

`sudo mount ~/Desktop/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso ~/cd-image -o loop`

After that the upgrade dialog should pop up.

Comment: you cannot under any circumstances upgrade direct from 10.04 to 11.04

Comment: @fossfreedom ofcource! did Rahul edit the question or someone? i thoug it is from 10.10 to 11.04. If from 10.04 to 11.04 i will edite my question. thanks