# Skipping intermediate Ubuntu OS upgrade to latest one,How do I upgrade from 9.04 to 10.04.2?

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, 9.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I skip over releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases)
>   [Is it possible to skip releases during an upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45666/is-it-possible-to-skip-releases-during-an-upgrade)

I'm currently runing Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty. I want to upgrade to 10.04.02, but whenever I use the Update manager to do this, it fails with the error "An upgrade from 'jaunty' to 'lucid' is not supported with this tool".

I also tried to run `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`, but it fails with the same error message:

```
  Checking for a new ubuntu release
  Done Upgrade tool signature
  Done Upgrade tool
  Done downloading            
  extracting 'lucid.tar.gz'
  authenticate 'lucid.tar.gz' against 'lucid.tar.gz.gpg'
  tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

  Reading cache

  Checking package manager

  Can not upgrade

  An upgrade from 'jaunty' to 'lucid' is not supported with this tool.
```