# Upgrade remote server from 9.04 to Ubuntu LTS

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, 9.04, vps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Skipping intermediate Ubuntu OS upgrade to latest one,How do I upgrade from 9.04 to 10.04.2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47807/skipping-intermediate-ubuntu-os-upgrade-to-latest-one-how-do-i-upgrade-from-9-04)

My situation: I'm stuck with a VPS which I have no physical access to. The VPS currently runs Ubuntu 9.04 and I'd like to upgrade to 10.04.

How would I go about doing this? (A fresh install would be fine. I have a complete backup of the server.)

---

I've tried to do `do-release-upgrade` but it gives

```
Can not upgrade.

An upgrade from 'jaunty' to 'lucid' is not supported with this tool.
```

Comment: I also stuck in the exact same situation if you find answer plz do post it here . thx

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do a fresh install. It would ensure that nothing is broken, as that's almost a guarantee if you were to add Lucid's repos to your 9.04 installation or upgrade incrementally through the GUI like Zkriesse said.

**EDIT:** You can upgrade to 10.04 via SSH by first editing `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` with your favourite editor and changing `Prompt=*` to `Prompt=lts` and then executing `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Source: http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-10-04-from-ubuntu-9-108-04-lts

Comment: any hints / url on how to do that over SSH?

Comment: added to the answer