# Why is Karmic (9.10) neither available from "releases" nor from "old-releases"?

Tags: 9.10, release-management

I need to upgrade an old install of Jaunty (9.04). Following the guide from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47807/how-do-i-upgrade-from-9-04-to-10-04-2), I wanted to download a CD image for Karmic, but it's neither available from http://releases.ubuntu.com nor from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com.

All the other releases (even the EOL ones) are [listed here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) except for Karmic, Is there a reason for that?

(It seems that it can still be downloaded via torrent.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're waiting for a new machine with some more storage to come on line (should be within next couple of days).   As soon as its available,  Karmic images will be back.