# Upgrading Server 9.10

Tags: upgrade, 9.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software on an old now unsupported Ubuntu version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-on-an-old-now-unsupported-ubuntu-version)

I have Ubuntu 9.10 server. Today when I tried to use `apt-get upgrade` I got 404 Not Found errors on each package. I've checked the repo directories manually and in fact there are no such verions of files requested by the apt. What should I do? Please help...

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [Ubuntu Releases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)#Releases) Paragraph about Ubuntu on wikipedia, version 9.10 is too old (End Of Life) and is not supported anymore (even the server version).

You can find the repositories under the "old-releases" server http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

The first step here is to back up anything you could lose. After that, my opinion is that your best option is to clean install a new version and restore the backup.

If a clean install is not feasible

### Upgrading

> EDIT: Rereading the source links I noticed that the upgrade method
>   I've reported here could no longer work. I'll follow up once I know
>   better.
>
> EDIT2: The problem happens in the upgrade from 9.04 to 9.10 because both of them
>   are out of support, as discussed in this thread in AskUbuntu: [Skipping intermediate Ubuntu OS upgrade to latest one,How do I upgrade from 9.04 to 10.04.2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47807/skipping-intermediate-ubuntu-os-upgrade-to-latest-one-how-do-i-upgrade-from-9-04) .
>   Since 10.04 is supported I think the procedure below should be safe (but still risky)

The second best bet is to upgrade to a newer release (and you should do so as often as possible when a LTS version is released, in my opinion). It's important that you read about [End Of Life Upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades). What follows is taken from there, but not as complete as that page.

Since you haven't upgraded in time, you have some extra steps to follow.

**Always do a backup, I've never tried this procedure myself, so try at your own risk**.

First edit /etc/apt/sources.list like this to point the repository to old-releases. Notice that 9.10 (your current installed release) is codenamed karmic, so we use that. (if you have "backports" or "proposed" section of the repository activated, remove the "#" before their line)

```
## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Optional
#deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Update with the new sources

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade
```

Install update-manager-core if not already installed

```
sudo aptitude install update-manager-core
```

The installation of the following packages (server kernel) is also required

```
sudo aptitude install linux-image-server linux-headers-server
```

You can now upgrade with this command, as mentioned in the "[Upgrading Ubuntu server](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/installing-upgrading.html)" for the release 10.04 (this is the release after the one you have installed)

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I suggest that before that you take a look at the [Ubuntu server guide index](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/index.html) for the release 10.04. Notice that even 10.04 is not the latest release, but at least is the lastest LTS and still supported.

[Source on End Of Life Upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)
[Source for jaunty, the procedure should be similar](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/Jaunty)