# Can I upgrade from 10.04 to 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, 10.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to upgrade straight from 10.04 to 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45666/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-straight-from-10-04-to-11-04)

I am using Ubuntu 10.04. I have now a 11.10 DVD. How can I upgrade to this version without loss of data and reformatting the hard disk?

Comment: (I actually would have marked this as a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/q/34430/18612, which I think has a better title to cover these types of questions, but that one was marked a dupe itself of the first.)